# segmentation fault: core dumped while accesing csv records from a file

Tags: c++, csv, segmentation-fault, coredump

I am working on a college c++ project and creating a function that parses a csv file and reads records stored in it. But it gives me an error everytime I use that function

csv file example:

```
9138119,913811921297,Shivam,J,Jha,3811921297,sj@g.c,DEL,sji2ns,100,sj@bank
```

I tried using reserve() function of vector

```
void person::login(){
   bool found = false;

   fstream fin;
   fin.open("acc_info.csv", ios:: in);

   string CRN, Password;
   cout << "\nEnter CRN: ";
   getline(cin, CRN);

   cout << "\nEnter password :";
   getline(cin, Password);

   vector<string> record;
   string line, word, temp;

   if(fin){
      while(fin >> temp){
         record.clear();
         getline(fin, line);
         stringstream s(line);

         while(getline(s, word, ',')){
            record.push_back(word);
         }

         if(CRN == record[0] && Password == record[10]){
            found = true;
            cout << "\nLogin successfull!\n\n";
            break;
         }
      }
      if(!found){
         cout << "\nWrong CRN and password entered\n\n";
      }
   }
   else{
      cout << "\nTechnical fault occured.. try again after some time!!\n\n";
   }
}
```

It should match the CRN and password as entered by user and provide whether successful login or not

> Here is the person class:

```
class person {

    public:
        void welcome();
        void show_account();
        void after_user_choice(int);
        void create_acc();
        void login();
        void accounts();
        void deposit();
        void cards();
        void loans();
        void insurance();
        void investments();
        int check(int, int, int);
        bool d;
        string retacno() const{
            return acc_no;
        }

        ~person();


        int x=5;

    protected:
        void show_acc_info(const unsigned long int);


        string firstname , middlename , lastname , address  , pan_no , fname ;
        string password, mobile_no ;
        string acc_no, crn, balance= "100";
        string email_id;
        string line, word, temp;

    private:
        string usr ; 
        string pswd;


};
```

> Here's how I took input from user to write to CSV file:

```
void person::create_acc(){

     ofstream xl("acc_info.csv" , ios::app );
         cout<<"ENTER FIRST NAME\n";
     getline(cin,firstname);

     cout<<"ENTER MIDDLE NAME \n";
     getline(cin,middlename);

     cout<<"ENTER LAST NAME: "<<endl;
     getline(cin,lastname);  

     cout<<"ENTER FATHER'S NAME: "<<endl;
     getline(cin,fname);  

     cout<<"ENTER YOUR EMAIL_ID: ";
     getline(cin,email_id);

     cout<<"ENTER PAN CARD NUMBER: "<<endl;
     getline(cin,pan_no);

     cout<<"ENTER YOUR RESIDENTIAL ADDRESS: "<<endl;
     getline(cin,address);  

     cout<<"ENTER YOUR MOBILE NUMBER: "<<endl;
     getline(cin, mobile_no);

    acc_no = to_string(910000000000 + stol(mobile_no, nullptr, 10)); //generating acc no;

    crn = to_string(int(stol(acc_no)/100000)); //generating crn;
     string repswrd;
     bool z;

    do{

     cout<<"ENTER PASSWORD FOR YOUR CRN(USER_ACC): ";
     getline(cin,password);    

     cout<<"RE-ENTER YOUR PASSWORD: ";
     getline(cin,repswrd);

     if(!(password.compare(repswrd))){

           cout<<"Passwords matched succesfully!"<<endl<<endl;
           z = true;
           }
     else{

          cout<<"Passwords didn't match!!! Try again\n"<<endl;
          z = false;
               }

         }while(!z);

      cout<<"\n\nAccount created successfully\n\n";

      cout << "Customer Satisfaction is our main"
           << "priority, so we have deposited a "
           << "sum of Rs. 100 into your bank a/c"
           << endl << endl;

     xl<<crn<<","
      << acc_no<< ","
     << firstname << "," 
     << middlename << "," 
     << lastname<< ","
     << mobile_no<< ","
     <<email_id<<","
     << address<< ","
     <<pan_no<<","
     <<balance << ","
     << password<< "\n";

     xl.close();

     cout<<endl;  

     }
```

Comment: At ` if(CRN == record[0] && Password == record[10])` How can you be sure that record has 10 entries?

Comment: `if(CRN == record[0] && Password == record[10]){` -- Change that to `record.at(0)` and `record.at(10)`.  If there are no such records, you will get an `out_of_range` exception thrown.

Comment: Just added a sreenshot. The record has 11 entries

Comment: *The record has 11 entries* -- No, please verify that the vector has those entries.  Never write code that assumes these things.  Also, please, no images.  Put the data in the question, preferably in the code.

Comment: In addition, please post a [mcve].  You posted a member function of a class, and if that member function is non-static, we need to know if that `person` object is valid.

Comment: If the line marked in the picture is the full content of `acc_info.csv` then your `record` will contain `0` entries. Edit: Hmm, it will _always_ contain `0` entries.

Comment: @TedLyngmo how is that?

Comment: You mix formatted input and unformatted input. Can you please include an example of the `csv` file as text in the question?

Comment: okay sure: 9138119,913811921297,Shivam,J,Jha,3811921297,sj@g.c,DEL,sji2ns,100,sj@bank

Comment: All that goes into `temp`

Comment: @ShivamJha still not a [mcve]. The true beauty of the [mcve] is it's a very useful debugging technique. It's hard to make one without discovering and fixing the bug along the way. While constantly asking for one might make us seem pedantic, if you created the [mcve] before asking the question odds are very good you wouldn't have to ask the question.

Comment: okay @TedLyngmo what should I do now? so that the core is not dumped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while(fin >> temp)` reads the line and puts it in `temp` but you don't use it, so `line` will be empty, even if followed by another valid line in the file.
`>>` leaves the newline character in the stream which is the only thing the following `std::getline` will read. It'll always read empty lines as long as the lines in the file don't contain characters that would make `>>` split it, like whitespace characters.

Consider just using `std::getline` to skip formatted input and actually check that you got a valid record before indexing:

```
    if(fin) {
        while(std::getline(fin, line)) {
            record.clear();
            stringstream s(line);

            while(std::getline(s, word, ',')) {
                record.push_back(word);
            }

            // check that you've got a valid record
            if(record.size() != 11)
                throw std::runtime_error("invalid record size (" +
                                         std::to_string(record.size()) + ")");

            if(CRN == record[0] && Password == record[10]) {
                found = true;
                cout << "\nLogin successful!\n\n";
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found) {
            cout << "\nWrong CRN and password entered\n\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much Ted Lyngmo. I've been trying to find this issue for couple of hours , you saved me!

Comment: yes sure man, it did help me alot.. in fact you saved my project! good to find you man! :)

Comment: lol ma! now i know how to accept an answer!! thank you once again again!!!

Comment: @ShivamJha debugging tip: throw in some extra print statements to make sure you're reading what you think you are reading. `while(getline(s, word, ',')){ record.push_back(word); cout << word << endl; }` would have quickly shown you weren't reading anything.  The next logical thing to look at after that would have been `cout << temp << endl;` and that would have solved the mystery.